# How do you hide an element in JQuery when posting data to .html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar and I do a search within a modal.  Everything works fine, except when I do that search it wants to load the navbar into the modal.

I just want to hide the navbar or prevent it from loading. So I created a `.hide3` class.  I was hoping the `.not()` JQuery function would stop it from loading, but I must be missing something.

```
$("#submit_search").click(function(){
    var searchID= btn.data('mylink');
    $.post("search.php?&searchID="+searchID,function(data) {
        $('#search_results_div').html(data).not('.hide3');      
         // I also tried $('.hide3').hide(); here but it hides the main navbar and not the new one created.
    });
});     

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top hide3" role="navigation">
   // content here
```

Comment: I just want to hide the navbar when loading the data into the html.  It loads a whole webpage into the search.

Comment: Try to make it a partial view. make provision on your search.php page with certain flag that when it is called with that flag, it should not load its master view content (header/footer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $.post("search.php?&searchID="+searchID,function(data) {
    $(data).find(".hide3").remove();
    $('#search_results_div').html(data);      
});
```

OR assuming there is never a nav bar to be shown inside the search result div

CSS:

```
#search_result_div .hide3 { display:none }
```

OR PHP:

```
if (!isset($_POST["searchID"])) { ?>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top hide3" role="navigation">
<?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: Genius!  PHP will probably work best.  I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose data contains HTML and the navbar you want to hide is in the data.
First use jquery to remove navbar from data and then set it.

```
var $html = $(data);
$html.find('.hide3').hide(); //personally I prefer add a class which hides the content using CSS
$('#search_results_div').html($html);
```

Comment: unfortunately this one hides everything for some reason.

Comment: I like your idea of .append a class.